# Django passing variables to modules - login() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

In my Django urls.py, I have a login page:

`(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', { 'design_form': True }),`

I want to pass a variable 'design_form': True to django.contrib.auth.views.login, so that my accounts/login page displays the way that I want it to. `django.contrib.auth.views.login` bypasses views.py, so I have no chance of doing

```
variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'design_form': True,
    })
```

as I usually would. So how do I pass variables to the module without getting the `login() got an unexpected keyword argument` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `extra_context` variable you can pass to the login view. Use it like this:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', { 'extra_context' : {'design_form': True }}),
```

That will put `design_form` in the context for the template.